# Minecraft keeps crashing with JRE error

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I've been playing Minecraft for 5 days now and the whole time I've been playing, I came across two errors. One is that the Java TM binary thing isn't responding.  The other is when I'm playing for a bit, the whole games completely closes and it takes me to the game output spot in the Minecraft launcher. This is what it says:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff88f41d683, pid=7860, tid=8872
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig7icd64.dll+0x6d683]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\christopher\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid7860.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

Comment: Try https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/minecraft-64bit-java-error-exception_access_violation-0xc0000005.32934/

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say with Minecraft, as there are many different reasons for crashing. However, there are a few things you could try:

1. Increase the RAM allocation:You can do this by opening the Minecraft launcher, clicking "edit profile", then in the "Java Settings (Advanced)" tick the "JVM arguments" box and replacing Xmx1G with Xmx2G or a larger number if you have a lot of RAM in your computer. I don't recommend leaving any less than 1G unallocated, i.e. if you have 4 Gigabytes of RAM, only add 3 at most. This is probably the most common problem when Minecraft stops working apparently randomly, because it can cause crashing if your game world gets too big.
2. Like Gert says, if you are using any mods, you could try deleting your Minecraft appdata folder (but backup your saves on the desktop first!) and then the launcher will automatically re-download a fresh copy.
3. Your Java could be outdated. You can probably get the newest version here: https://java.com/en/download/

Answer (score -2):

Remove **all mods** installed and test again. If all fails, uninstall minecraft then go to %appdata% then delete the .minecraft folder and reinstall the game